# Notification URL using authorize.net ARB

Tags: php, authorize.net, recurring-billing

I am trying to integrate authorize.net payment gateway in my e-commerce based website. The payment is recurrent, so I am using Authorize.net Automated Recurrent Billing (ARP) API here : http://developer.authorize.net/api/arb/

Now, I would like to know if it is possible to configure the notification url in the API ?

I read, that I can configure the silent post URL in the account settings here :

https://sandbox.authorize.net/UI/themes/sandbox/merch.aspx?page=settings&sub=adcsilent&xhtml=ADCSilent-settings&operation=get

I am trying to set the notification URL in the API iteself.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot set it in the API call. It can only be set in the account settings.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that. Big fan of your website, It really helped me a lot.